# Http POST request taking lot of time to complete - net/http - Go

Tags: post, go, net-http

I am using net/http in Go, and one of my HTTPS POST request is taking lot of time like approx 16 seconds to complete . Though the backend server processing is only taking 2.2 seconds but over all process (when the response is received from the REST API after full processing ) is like 16 seconds .

My call looks like :

```
https://xxxxx.com/abcded
```

And the body has a JSON which contains a GIF file base64 of size approx 1.68 MB

```
{
  "username": "test",
  "update_username": "0",
  "name": "test name",
  "isprivate": "0",
  "avatar_url": "",
  "description": "I am Test , updated using api ",
  "location": "test world",
  "phone": "12345678",
  "age": "23",
  "gender": "m",
  "update_profilepic": "1",
  "profilepic_lat": "28.593",
  "profilepic_lon": "77.1981",
  "profilepic_height": "480",
  "profilepic_width": "480",
  "profilepic_type": "photo",
  "profilepic": "Dummy String due to Size Constraint in StackOverFlow"
}
```

Details :

The POST request was invoked from the client (Postman) at 16:59:00.100 But the server recieves the call at 16:59:13.240 (which is shown in the Server logs below) . And finally the server does all the processing and responds back at 16:59:15.073 . And finally I recieved the response code at the client (Postman) at 16:59:15.773

```
Server Logs Start *****************************************

16:59:13.240
Just Entered into AUTHENTICATION method
16:59:13.246
--------------In Profile Related--------------
16:59:13.246
--------------In Edit Setting--------------
16:59:13.363
---------- In Edit Setting --------
16:59:13.363
Username direct rcvd :%!(EXTRA string=morninglad)
16:59:13.363
Username rcvd :%!(EXTRA string=morninglad)
16:59:13.363
Name rcvd :%!(EXTRA string=morning)
16:59:13.363
Update NON USER NAME UPDATE FLAG RCVD
16:59:13.363
About to call Update Query
16:59:13.374
About to Update the Profile Pic as found the flag
16:59:13.374
Updating the Profile Pic------------
16:59:14.906
About to Insert Media into DB
16:59:14.906
Got the GeoHash :%!(EXTRA string=ttnc9j3tgujw)
16:59:14.952
Found location :%!(EXTRA string=Gurugram)
16:59:14.955
Media Play value is :%!(EXTRA string=)
16:59:14.955
Username :%!(EXTRA string=morninglad)
16:59:14.983
Updating the Profile Pic Done ------------
16:59:14.983
Profile Pic Updated !
16:59:15.041
-------------------Fetch Avatars-----------------
16:59:15.073
The Avatar URL got :Avatar1
16:59:15.073
The Avatar URL got : Avatar2
16:59:15.073
---------- In Edit Setting DONE - END --------
16:59:15.073
--------------Response SENT--------------

Server Logs End *****************************************
```

So if I go by the above mentioned timestamps ,then time to reach to server was almost 13 seconds , and the total processing time of server was about 2 seconds . And finally recieved the response code in within 1 second.So total time is like 16 seconds for this call.

So I was trying to figure out why the call to reach to server is taking 13 seconds ?

When I am invoking the same call with the smaller body i.e instead of GIF of 1.68 MB to JPEG of 1.4 KB the total time is like 2.2 seconds . So shall I assume that this body size is the reason for increased time ?

But with the kind of internet I am working on (Download speed - 72.33 Mbps and Upload Speed - 6.07 Mbps)this sounds weird .

Any pointer if I am doing something wrong over here ?

Comment: Did you also check your server? It can have limits also on receiving requests.

Comment: @KorbenDallas server is fine , I have already checked it .

Comment: How did you checked it? Did you try to download GIF directly to server without GO with `scp` for example?